# How to convert long number (string) in php to 32 bytes buffer?

Tags: php, byte, long-integer, data-conversion

I am trying to convert this long number:
7066362913544046959379121391986018585750267357944410108207023200264959783199

to 32 bytes buffer.

I was able to do this in python using the following code:

```
x = "7066362913544046959379121391986018585750267357944410108207023200264959783199"
x_int = int(x)
x_in_bytes = (x_int).to_bytes(32, byteorder='little')
```

Is it possible to the same in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you're going to be using [intval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) method and the [pack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) method.

The code will look like this:

```
<?php

$x = "7066362913544046959379121391986018585750267357944410108207023200264959783199";
$xInt = intval($x);
$xBytes = pack('L', $xInt);

?>
```

The 'L' string is the format (unsigned long, always 32 bit, machine byte order). The format string consists of format codes followed by an optional repeater argument. Read more about this in the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php).

Comment: Thanks for the replying. The value of `$xInt` will not be the same as `$x` however since php has MAX_INT to 2^63, the value of $xInt will be 9223372036854775807.

Comment: That's correct, I notice this now. You could leave out that line and directly convert `$x` to bytes using the `pack` method.